# Beginning balance column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction table that collects positive and negative amounts by date, account number, and project number.  And I need a result set that produces a beginning balance column summing all of the amounts prior to the start date of the period I am running the query.  I'm accomplishing this now by a function for the beginning balance but it is runtime is taking longer than 4 minutes for a 3,000 - row record set (too long). What is the best way to accomplish the same result set?

My current attempt

```
Select sftpUser.BeginBal(@startDate,a.ProjectID) as BeginBal,
    a.accountnum, a.AccountDesc, a.JournalRef, a.Projectid, a.ProjDesc, sum(a.amount) as PeriodAmount, b.donorstmtdesc as ProjectName,
    (case when substring(a.accountnum,4,4) in ('4000','4025','4900','4920','4930','4940','5060','5400') then 0 else 1 end) as Grp2,
    (case when substring(a.accountnum,4,4) in ('4000','4025') then 0
          when substring(a.accountnum,4,4) in ('4900','4920','4930','4940','5060','5400') then 1
                  when substring(a.accountnum,4,4) = '6000' then 2
          else 3 end) as RptLn
    from activity a
    left outer join sftpuser.projects b on a.ProjectID=b.projectid
    Where a.PostStatus='Posted' and a.PostDate between @startdate and @enddate and a.ProjectID in (Select ProjID from sftpUser.ProjectID_Split(@ProjID,','))
    Group by a.accountnum, a.AccountDesc, a.JournalRef, a.ProjectID, a.ProjDesc, b.donorstmtdesc
```

[sftpUser.BeginBal Function]
Create Function [sftpUser].[BeginBal] (@asof date, @ProjectID as varchar(50))
Returns Money
as Begin
Return (Select sum(a.amount) as BeginBal from sftpUser.activity a where poststatus='Posted' and PostDate<@asof and a.ProjectID=@Projectid)

End

```
[Activity Table]
|:ID:|:TransNum:|:PostStatus:|:journal:|:journalref|:accountnum:|:accountdesc:|:amount:|:projectID:|:projectdesc:|
|:1:|:6452-177:|:2022-01-07:|:Posted:|:Accounts Payable:|:St. Petersburg College-Vet Tech Dog Yard Re:|:02-6020-03:|:Capital Facilities Expenditures:|:400.00:|:DERBY CAP:|:Derby Lane Charity Day:|
|:2:|:6452-183:|:2022-01-07:|:Posted:|:Accounts Payable:|:Barnes & Noble College Booksellers, LLC-Book Awards 2021-22:|:02-6000-03:|:Scholarship Expenditures:|:    138.99:|:FND PARTNERS:|:Foundation Partners Group Scholarship Fund
```

[Result Set]
|:BeginBal:|:accountNum:|:accountdesc:|:journalref:|:projectid:|:projectdesc:|:periodamount:|:projectname:|:grp2:|:rptln:|
|:-297207.98|:01-4000-013|:Contributions|:ACH WePay Fidelity Match|:TITAN|:SPC Titan Fund|:-500|:St. Petersburg College Titan Fund:|0|:0|
|:-297207.98|:01-4000-013|:Contributions|:Adams Jeffrey Credit Card|:TITAN|:SPC Titan Fund|:-250|:St. Petersburg College Titan Fund:|0|:0|
|:-297207.98|:01-4000-013|:Contributions|:Adjust Batch 6641 / 2022-165|:TITAN|:SPC Titan Fund|:-50|:St. Petersburg College Titan Fund:|0|:0|
|:-297207.98|:01-4000-013|:Contributions|:Allen David Personal Chec|:TITAN|:SPC Titan Fund|:-30.78|:St. Petersburg College Titan Fund:|0|:0|
|:-297207.98|:01-4000-013|:Contributions|:AmazonSmile Charities  Personal Chec|:TITAN|:SPC Titan Fund|:-75|:St. Petersburg College Titan Fund:|0|:0|

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results to illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You would probably be better off moving your aggregation into a *cross apply* - impossible to answer though without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and details of the tables, indexes and the *actual execution plan*

Comment: Also `sftpUser.BeginBal()` is going to be an inline scalar function (RBAR) where we have no idea what's going on

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.  Added an image of the desired result set...  Here is the function as requested.     
 
ALTER Function [sftpUser].[BeginBal] (@asof date, @ProjectID as varchar(50)) 
Returns Money
 as Begin
 Return (Select sum(a.amount) as BeginBal from sftpUser.activity a where poststatus='Posted' and PostDate<@asof and a.ProjectID=@Projectid)

Comment: Edit your question to add clarity, not in the comments. And see how not to use [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors

Comment: It's not okay to use screenshots to show sample data or results.

Comment: I think you want to use a Common Table Expression to get your beginning balance, then do an INNER JOIN with the CTE.  You may also need to add some non-clustered indexes (prob AccountNum)

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously a lot more going on in the query you posted than your question is asking about.

Without the example data it's hard to be sure of exactly what we're working with here, but here's a technique that doesn't use a scalar function and instead leverages windowed functions.

```
DECLARE @ledger TABLE (AccountNumber BIGINT, TransactionAmount DECIMAL(10,4), TransactionDateTimeUTC DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @ledger (AccountNumber, TransactionAmount, TransactionDateTimeUTC) VALUES
(1,10,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'), (1,10,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'), (1,-2,'2022-11-10 05:23:16'),  (1,6,'2022-11-18 05:23:16'),    (1,.99,'2022-11-18 09:23:16'), (1,-187.50,'2022-11-29 05:23:16'),
(2,54,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'), (2,54,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'), (2,22,'2022-11-10 05:23:16'),  (2,-25.2,'2022-11-18 05:23:16'),(2,8,'2022-11-18 09:23:16'),   (2,-17.50,'2022-11-29 05:23:16'),
(3,-12,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'),(3,-12,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'),(3,19.5,'2022-11-10 05:23:16'),(3,33,'2022-11-18 05:23:16'),   (3,2.5,'2022-11-18 09:23:16'), (3,187.50,'2022-11-29 05:23:16'),
(4,13,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'), (4,13,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'), (4,2,'2022-11-10 05:23:16'),   (4,1,'2022-11-18 05:23:16'),    (4,-0.1,'2022-11-18 09:23:16'),(4,-1.50,'2022-11-29 05:23:16'),
(5,333,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'),(5,333,'2022-10-31 05:23:16'),(5,-0.5,'2022-11-10 05:23:16'),(5,99,'2022-11-18 05:23:16'),   (5,-5,'2022-11-18 09:23:16'),  (5,7,'2022-11-29 05:23:16')

DECLARE @LastPeriodDateTimeUTC DATETIME = '2022-10-31 23:59:59.997'

SELECT *, SUM(a.TransactionAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.AccountNumber ORDER BY a.TransactionDateTimeUTC) AS RunningTotal
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber,
               CASE WHEN TransactionDateTimeUTC < @LastPeriodDateTimeUTC THEN @LastPeriodDateTimeUTC ELSE TransactionDateTimeUTC END AS TransactionDateTimeUTC,
               CASE WHEN TransactionDateTimeUTC < @LastPeriodDateTimeUTC THEN 
                    SUM(TransactionAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber, CASE WHEN TransactionDateTimeUTC < @LastPeriodDateTimeUTC THEN @LastPeriodDateTimeUTC ELSE TransactionDateTimeUTC END ORDER BY TransactionDateTimeUTC)
                    ELSE TransactionAmount END AS TransactionAmount
          FROM @ledger
       ) a
```

```
AccountNumber   TransactionDateTimeUTC  TransactionAmount   RunningTotal
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               2022-10-31 23:59:59.997 20.0000             20.0000
1               2022-11-10 05:23:16.000 -2.0000             18.0000
1               2022-11-18 05:23:16.000 6.0000              24.0000
1               2022-11-18 09:23:16.000 0.9900              24.9900
1               2022-11-29 05:23:16.000 -187.5000           -162.5100
2               2022-10-31 23:59:59.997 108.0000            108.0000
2               2022-11-10 05:23:16.000 22.0000             130.0000
2               2022-11-18 05:23:16.000 -25.2000            104.8000
2               2022-11-18 09:23:16.000 8.0000              112.8000
2               2022-11-29 05:23:16.000 -17.5000            95.3000
```

Essentially we're grouping up anything prior to the current period (based off of the @LastPeriodDateTimeUTC variable being the end of the previous period) and rolling that up into 1 row. From there we can calculate a running total using SUM() OVER for each account number in TransactionDateTimeUTC order.